# When to specify data length on ALTER TABLE when adding a column

Tags: oracle, plsql, alter-table

I am writing pl/sql code with dynamic sql statements to ALTER TABLE on table B when new columns are found in table A. When I query all_tab_columns from table a I can return all I need to do this, but in some cases it throws an error when I specify a length for the new column in table B (for example, DATE which I expected). So, I need to parse the results from all_tab_columns to include or exclude a length in the ALTER TABLE statement. On which data types should I leave off a length specification?

Comment: The question is not clear. Yes, DATE does not have a length. Is the DATE column being added to table B, when you find the same column in table A and it is missing in table B? What is the data type of that column in table A? Is it not also DATE? If it is DATE in table A, what "length" are you reading for it in ALL_TAB_COLUMNS? Or is it, instead, a VARCHAR2 column which you are converting (as you should!) to proper DATE data type?

Comment: In general, only CHAR and VARCHAR2 column declarations *require* length in ALTER TABLE. DATE does not have length. TIMESTAMP allows you to specify precision of fraction of a second; NUMBER allows you to specify precision and scale. But these are not required, and unless you use them as constraints, you don't need to worry about them.

Comment: The `data_length` column in the `*_tab_columns` views is set for date type; 7 for `DATE`, 11 for `TIMESTAMP`, etc. reflecting their internal storage size. And `data_scale` is also set for timestamps, even through that is included in the `data_type`.So you don't need to refer to either of those explicitly. [The documented data types](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020) show which take arguments. Are you dealing with somethign not listed there? (Notice that you may need to specify character or byte semantics for `varchar2` columns too.)

Comment: Look at CHAR_COL_DECL_LENGTH in all_tab_columns

Comment: Thanks for the input, and sorry if the question wasn't clear. The answers all of you provided were very helpful. I think I've got it all working the way it should now. Thank you!